# What is stable history in a database?

Tags: replication, database-theory

I am reading the paper *Making geo-replication fast as possible, consistent when necessary* by Li et al. in which they propose a geo-replication system called "RedBlue Consistency". They have a table which compares a couple of systems that have implemented geo-replication with several desired properties.
One of the properties is called "stable histories", and their description is:

> the system should provide a set of stable histories, meaning that user actions cannot be undone;

I don't fully understand this part, what do they mean by "user actions cannot be undone"?

Here is a link to the paper and a video of the talk: https://www.usenix.org/conference/osdi12/technical-sessions/presentation/li

Comment: I'm adding it as a comment rather than an answer as I'm not 100% (and "stable histories" isn't a standard database term) but my understanding is that by geo-replicating data, you then have more than one copy of the data, with some data being immediately available across all nodes with "fast" replication, and some being slower replicated but "eventually consistent". In which case you don't want a situation where a user action (such as posting a Facebook status) can be "undone" through another of the replicas not including that update. Once committed, it's committed.. Interesting paper BTW!

Comment: I see, so it is more about the system potentially undoing  a user's action, not that the user cannot undo his own actions. The formulation in the paper wasn't very clear to me, thanks for your insight!